# Forwarding the output of ls -l to 'scanf' in my C program

Tags: c, pipe, scanf

I'm pretty new to C programming so bear with me here as I try to work through my problem.

I am writing a C program that takes the output of running

```
system("ls -l")
```

and then pipes it into `scanf` for it to be checked against certain conditions set by the user in the command line arguments when running the C program.

I have looked around on here as well as other resources and all examples or explanations were either very brief or used way too many  shortcuts when explaining how it's done. If someone could give me a more layman explanation of the process I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Learn about `fork` and `popen`. `system` is irrelevant.

Comment: There are two problems with your approach, although if you've already decided this is the approach you're going to use, my comments are irrelevant.  (1) `scanf` is, despite its popularity, a poor tool for doing this kind of parsing. If I were trying to parse `ls` output, I'd use other techniques. (2) The data you're looking for is much more straightforwardly available by calling functions like `stat` and `readdir`.

Comment: The `system` function on a POSIX system (like e.g. Linux) spawns a shell that execute the command. The `system` function returns an integer value indicating success or failure, nothing more. You can't *pipe* that into `scanf` in any way. What you *can* to is to use the [`popen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) function and use `fscanf` (or other standard C input functions) to read the output from the program being executed.

Comment: I should have specified, I am doing this for a school assignment that is why I didn't ask for a straight answer but more of an explanation of the process. I am told that I have to use the output of "/bin/ls -l" as stdin. Like I mentioned in my original post. I am still new to C and am trying to do my best to understand so excuse me if I seem a little slow here.

Comment: In this case they mean that the output is just piped into your program. No `system` involved. Just think that this output is typed from keyboard. It will get invoked as `> ls -l | ./yourprogram`. That's it.